# Want to Receive dynamic length data from a message queue in IPC?

Tags: c, ipc, message-queue

Here I have to send and receive dynamic data using a SysV message queue.

so in structure filed i have dynamic memory allocation `char *` because  its size may be varies.

so how can i receive this type of message at receiver side.

Please let me know how can i send dynamic length of data with message queue.

I am getting problem in this i posted my code below.

**send.c**

```
/*filename   : send.c
 *To compile : gcc send.c -o send
 */
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/ipc.h>
#include <sys/msg.h>

struct my_msgbuf {
    long mtype;
    char *mtext;
};

int main(void)
{
    struct my_msgbuf buf;
    int msqid;
    key_t key;
    static int count = 0;
    char temp[5];
    int run = 1;
    if ((key = ftok("send.c", 'B')) == -1) {
        perror("ftok");
        exit(1);
    }

    printf("send.c Key is = %d\n",key);

    if ((msqid = msgget(key, 0644 | IPC_CREAT)) == -1) {
        perror("msgget");
        exit(1);
    }

    printf("Enter lines of text, ^D to quit:\n");

    buf.mtype = 1; /* we don't really care in this case */
    int ret = -1;
    while(run) {
        count++;
        buf.mtext = malloc(50);
        strcpy(buf.mtext,"Hi hello test message here");
        snprintf(temp, sizeof (temp), "%d",count);
        strcat(buf.mtext,temp);
        int len = strlen(buf.mtext);
        /* ditch newline at end, if it exists */
        if (buf.mtext[len-1] == '\n') buf.mtext[len-1] = '\0';
        if (msgsnd(msqid, &buf, len+1, IPC_NOWAIT) == -1) /* +1 for '\0' */
        perror("msgsnd");
        if(count == 100)
            run = 0;
        usleep(1000000);
    }

    if (msgctl(msqid, IPC_RMID, NULL) == -1) {
        perror("msgctl");
        exit(1);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

**receive.c**

```
/* filename   : receive.c
 * To compile : gcc receive.c -o receive
 */
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/ipc.h>
#include <sys/msg.h>

struct my_msgbuf {
    long mtype;
    char *mtext;
};

int main(void)
{
    struct my_msgbuf buf;
    int msqid;
    key_t key;

    if ((key = ftok("send.c", 'B')) == -1) {  /* same key as send.c */
        perror("ftok");
        exit(1);
    }

    if ((msqid = msgget(key, 0644)) == -1) { /* connect to the queue */
        perror("msgget");
        exit(1);
    }

    printf("test: ready to receive messages, captain.\n");

    for(;;) { /* receive never quits! */
        buf.mtext = malloc(50);
        if (msgrcv(msqid, &buf, 50, 0, 0) == -1) {
            perror("msgrcv");
            exit(1);
        }
        printf("test: \"%s\"\n", buf.mtext);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Why do you use `strcpy`, `snprintf` and `strcat`? Why not just use `snprintf`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A couple of ways to solve your problem are:

1. Make the messages fixed length.
2. Send a fixed length "header" that includes the message length.
3. Send a terminator, since you seem to send strings include the terminating `'\0'`.

**Edit:** How to use `msgsnd` and `msgrcv`:

Your usage of the structure and `msgsnd` is wrong, as the function expects the whole message to be one continuous memory area. Examples such as [this](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/iseries/v5r3/topic/apis/ipcmsgsn.htm) use a structure with normal fields in it, or like [this](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/msgsnd.html) (at the bottom) which uses a fixed length string array.

You can send dynamic data having the structure size being dynamic as well. The trick here is to use a small fixed-size structure, and allocate more data than is needed.

Lets rewrite parts of your example sender code:

```
struct my_msgbuf {
    long   mtype;     /* Message type, must be > 0 */
    char   mtext[1];  /* Some compilers allow `char mtext[0]` */
};

/* ... */


int count = 0;
while (count < 100) {
    count++;

    /* Put string in a temporary place */
    char tmp[64];
    snprintf(tmp, sizeof(tmp), "Hi hello test message here %d", count);

    /* +1 for the terminating '\0' */
    size_t msgsz = strlen(tmp) + 1;

    /* Allocate structure, and memory for the string, in one go */
    struct my_msgbuf *buf = malloc(sizeof(struct my_msgbuf) + msgsz);

    /* Set up the message structure */
    buf->mtype = 1;
    memcpy(buf->mtext, tmp, msgsz);

    /* And send the message */
    msgsnd(msgid, buf, msgsz, IPC_NOWAIT);

    /* Remember to free the allocated memory */
    free(buf);
}
```

The above code handles sending of dynamic strings, as long as the are less than 63 characters (the size of the temporary string minus one).

Unfortunately `msgrcv` doesn't really support receiving of dynamically sized data. This can be helped by not using the `MSG_NOERROR` flag, and check for error `E2BIG` and then using `realloc` to get a bigger message buffer.

Something like this for receiving:

```
/* Should start with larger allocation, using small just for example */
size_t msgsz = 8;
struct my_msgbuf *buf = NULL;

for (;;) {
    /* Allocate if `buf`  is NULL, otherwise reallocate */
    buf = realloc(buf, msgsz);

    /* Receive message */
    ssize_t rsz = msgrcv(msgid, buf, msgsz, 1, 0);

    if (rsz == -1) {
        if (errno == E2BIG)
            msgsz += 8;  /* Increase size to reallocate and try again */
        else {
            perror("msgrcv");
            break;
        }
    } else {
        /* Can use `buf->mtext` as a string, as it already is zero-terminated */
        printf("Received message of length %d bytes: \"%s\""\n", rsz, buf->mtext);
        break;
    }
}

if (buf != NULL)
    free(buf);
```

The above code for receiving only receives one single message. If you want it to match the sender which sends lots of messages, then put the receiving code in a function, and call it in a loop.

**DISCLAIMER:** This code is written directly in the browser, only reading the manual pages. I have not tested it.

Comment: How can i decide messages fixed length? I want to make it dynamic. May be problem in receive.c file. can u please suggest me some sample example for this.

Comment: @user1089679 Edited my answer to include some code on how to handle dynamic messages.

Comment: What about this mlen in sender code i think mlen = strlen(tmp). am i right?

Comment: @user1089679 Ah, that should be `msgsz`.

Comment: Thanks For Your Answer. I will put this concept in my requirements and let u knw if i will face any issue.

Comment: What about free of realloc(). I am getting problem in example which i describe here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11201990/error-in-realloc-or-free-in-message-queue-example

Comment: @user1089679 In the receiver, you free the message after the loop, and in the sender you free it right after `msgsnd` (it works as a copy is appended to the message queue.) Modified my code to include calls to `free`.

Comment: You Seen my problem which i given link in my above comment? It will be resolved if i will do this thing?

Comment: Thanks a lot its Resolved Please can u post your answer on my reallocate memory issue problem question which i given in above link  so i can aspect both answers.

Comment: @user1089679 Uhm, I'm not sure about what I did to solve the other problem? :)

Comment: Can we take 2 fileds which have dynamically allocation i tried but its not working. first dynamic filed was overwrite by second one because there are only offset difference is only 1. Are u understand my problem?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/13032/discussion-between-user1089679-and-joachim-pileborg)